# Arch + AwesomeWM Multimonitor xrandr configuration scaling issue

Tags: arch-linux, xrandr, awesome

As the title suggests, I'm running Arch Linux with AwesomeWM, no Display Environment. It is running from my Dell XPS 13" 9370 with Dell's docking station WD15 to connect 2 Dell s2415h monitors. For the most part everything is working well. Here is my question; Is there a way to fix some scaling issues I've noticed. In more detail, there are many things which appear much smaller than the rest of my windows. So small I can't read them. Such as the my xscreensaver login, when I launch wine applications, random file selection windows from browsers or other applications. I'm sure there are more I'm forgetting. I've also had to scale up my URxvt font sizes significantly. This issue occurs across all displays, not just the laptop or external ones specifically. Do I have something wrong with my configuration?

```
xrandr --dpi 330 --output eDP1 --primary --mode 3840x2160 --pos 9600x0 --rotate normal --scale 1x1 --output DP2-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 4800x0 --rotate normal --scale 2.5x2.5 --output DP2-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --scale 2.5x2.5
```

I also have in my `~/.Xresources`

```
Xft.dpi: 330
URxvt*font: xft:Menlo for Powerline:pixelsize=30
```

(Font doesn't matter, I've tried all different ones, always have to scale up)

Some of the questions I have in which I'm struggling to figure out which I think might lead to my answer;

Do I need to set the DPI in `~/.Xresources` since I have multiple DPI's?

Can I set multiple DPI's in my xrandr command?

Do you think scaling up my HiDPI XPS monitor is better than scaling down my external monitors?

Display Specs:

Dell XPS: 331 DPI 3840x2160 13.3" diagonal

Dell s2415h external monitors: 93 DPI 1920x1080 23.8" diagonal